# Prepend value to iterable

Tags: java, iterator

Say I have an `Iterable<T> iter`, and say I have an `Object v` that I want to prepend to the Iterable somehow.

I have this which seems wrong:

```
var x = List.of(iter);
x.add(v);
return x.iterator();
```

the above doesn't work because it wants me to do this instead:

```
 var x = List.of(iter);
 x.add((Iterable<T>)v);
 return x.iterator();
```

why doesn't it allow me to do this?:

```
 var x = List.of(iter);
 x.add((T)v);   // does not compile, expects Iterable<T> not T
 return x.iterator();
```

I must be doing something wrong..how can I prepend to an Iterable?

Comment: Note the `List.of` factory methods return an _unmodifiable_ list.

Comment: Convenient that it has an add method then isn't it? Not being sarcastic, just saying that's weird.

Comment: Java doesn't have separate interfaces for mutable and immutable collections, unfortunately. The documentation will tell you if the returned collection is unmodifiable. Trying to modify an unmodifiable collection will result in an `UnsupportedOperationException` at runtime.

Comment: Yeah i haven't done Java in awhile but that's pretty lame lol, whatever, not gonna shoot the messenger. Anyway do you know how to convert an iterable into something I can prepend to, and get back an iterable after I prepend?

Comment: yes I will need to convert the iterable to a list or whatever, just don't know how to do that

Comment: Not sure if this is your real code, but why not `var x = List.of((Iterable<T>)v, iter); return x.iterator();`?

Comment: sure that probably works can you explain why the iter argument is the second argument and v is the first arg?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to prepend an element to the `Iterable` or create a copy of the `Iterable` with the new element at the start? Or create a `List` of `Iterable`s?

Comment: Well if I could prepend directly to the iterable that would be nice but I don't think Java will let me, have to convert it to something else first, then prepend

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't allow you to do this :

```
var x = List.of(iter);
x.add((Iterable<T>)v);
return x.iterator();
```

Becasue I think,the List x contains object of type (Iterable).so it's necessary to cast Object that you want to add to the List in this type : (Iterable)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't get it to compile is because you end up with the following (not using `var` so the types are easily seen).

```
List<Iterable<T>> x = List.of(iter); // List of Iterable<T> with a single element: "iter"
x.add(v); // Won't compile because "v" is an Object, not an Iterable<T>

x.add((Iterable<T>) v); // Compiles with warnings, will probably fail with ClassCastException at runtime

x.add((T) v); // Won't compile, "v" is being cast to "T" which is not an Iterable<T>
```

Despite all that, the `List.of` factory methods return an *unmodifiable* `List`. Even if you could get it to compile you'd end up with an `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown at runtime.

---

The `Iterable` interface doesn't provide any API for adding elements, only removing elements through the `Iterator` (if the implementation supports it). This means you can't prepend an element to the `Iterable` in a general sense. If you need an API that provides an `Iterable` you can add elements to you shouldn't be returning an `Iterable` to begin with. Prefer returning `Collection` or, since you need to prepend elements, `List` or `Deque`. Note the mentioned alternatives all extend from the `Iterable` interface:

- Iterable

  - Collection

    - List
    - Set
    - Queue

      - Deque

If you must return `Iterable` for some reason, or the problem is a third party API, then the best option is to create a copy and add your elements to the copy.

```
Iterable<T> iter = ...;
Object v = ...;
List<Object> copy = new ArrayList<>();
copy.add(v); // add v first
iter.forEach(copy::add); // add rest of iterable after v
```

Notice the `List` is a list of `Object` now. You specified you have an `Iterable` of `T` that you want to add an `Object` to. Without more information the common ancestor between those two types is `Object`.

If you don't want a copy, and you know the implementation of `Iterable` is something like a *modifiable* `List`, you can cast then add:

```
((List<T>) iter).add(0, v); // in this case "v" must be of type "T"
```

However, the fact you have an `Iterable` indicates the API that produced it does not want nor expect it to be modified by you, the consumer of said API.